# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol error?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can any1 tell me why I'm getting this error.

template header file (prog.h):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional> 
using namespace std;

#ifndef H_PROG
#define H_PROG

// data files

#define D1 "data1.txt"

#define INT_SZ 4    // width of integer
#define FLT_SZ 7    // width of floating-pt number
#define STR_SZ 12   // width of string

#define INT_LN 15   // no of integers on single line
#define FLT_LN 9    // no of floating-pt nums on single line
#define STR_LN 5    // no of strings on single line

// function and class prototypes

// stores items from input file into vector
template < class T > 
void get_list ( vector < T >&, const char* );

#endif
```

`.cpp` file :

```cpp
#include "prog.h"
#include <fstream>


template < class T >
void get_list ( vector < T >& vector1, const char* filename )
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open(filename);
    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"File did not open."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        T data;
        while(infile)
        {
            infile>>data;
            vector1.insert(data);
        }
    }
}
```

in the main function I have :

```cpp
#include "prog.h"
#include <conio.h>

int main ( )
{
    vector < int >    v1;  
    vector < float >  v2;   
    vector < string > v3;  


    // first heap

    cout << "first heap - ascending order:\n\n";
    get_list(v1,D1);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

when i try to run this i get an error saying :

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl get_list(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator > &,char const *)" (??$get_list@H@@YAXAAV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main

Answer (score 3):

In `main.cpp` you only have visibility to the `get_list` declaration in `prog.h`. The definition in `prog.cpp` is not seen and so the template is not instantiated.

You can either explicitly instantiate the template for the types you care about in `prog.cpp` or you can put the `get_list` function definition into the `prog.h` header.

Normally you would put the definition of a template function into a header file so that it can be instantiated when used. In your case that would mean moving the contents of the `prog.cpp` file into `prog.h` and not having a `prog.cpp` file in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You did not link the `main.cpp` with the `other.cpp` file. The function prototype for `get_list` is there in `prog.h`, but the actual definition is not.

Comment: I have vector included in the prog.h file.

Comment: using namespace std is also in there.. and then i have included #include "prog.h" in the main function

Comment: If `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std;` are missing it will result in a compiler error not a linker error and especially not the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: @psj01, the answer is fixed